# How to apply SUM to one record based on the value in a column - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

I am trying to sum the values of one record based on the value in another column. I will try to explain using a dummy table and data.

table creation code:

```
create table test_prj_linking_t
(
prj_name varchar2(10),
prj_code varchar2(20),
prj_alt_code varchar2(50),
prj_bud1 number,
prj_bud2 number
)
```

insert statement:

```
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_ALT_CODE,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values     ('prj_A','A123','B123,C123',100,100);
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_ALT_CODE,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values ('prj_B','B123',null,200,200);
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_ALT_CODE,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values ('prj_C','C123',null,50,50);
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_ALT_CODE,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values ('prj_D','D123',null,70,70);
```

Intended Output: for a project whose prj_alt_code has prj_code of other projects, bud value should be added

For Prj_A, bud1 should come as 350, bud2 as 350 (sum of the bud values of prj_A,prj_B,prj_C)
For Prj_b, Prj_C, Prj_D there will be no summation of values

I was trying with something like this:

```
select prj_name,prj_code,
case
when prj_alt_code is not null
then
(select sum(t1.prj_bud1)
from test_prj_linking_t t1, test_prj_linking_t t2
where t1.prj_code=t2.prj_alt_code)
when prj_alt_code is null
then
(select t1.prj_bud1
from test_prj_linking_t t1)
end bud
from test_prj_linking_t
```

but this does not work when there are multiple records with NULL value for prj_alt_code, neither for a prj_alt_code having comma separated values (ex: B123,C123).

Please let me know how to do this in a select query.

Thanks & Regards,
Bishal Mandal

Comment: Keeping multiple values in a single cell is the worst idea in the world. Please, create another table to store prj_alt_code for particular projects, and things will simplify automagically.

Comment: there is no PL/SQL in your example.

Answer (score 0):

you should to change your data model to keep all attributes separatelly

```
create table test_prj_linking_t
(
prj_name varchar2(10),
prj_code varchar2(20),
prj_code_parent varchar2(20),
prj_bud1 number,
prj_bud2 number
)
```

after that, insert each prj_code with its parent separately ... it means:

```
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_CODE_PARENT,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values ('prj_A','A123',null,100,100);
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_CODE_PARENT,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values ('prj_B','B123','A123',200,200);
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_CODE_PARENT,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values ('prj_C','C123','A123',50,50);
Insert into TEST_PRJ_LINKING_T (PRJ_NAME,PRJ_CODE,PRJ_CODE_PARENT,PRJ_BUD1,PRJ_BUD2) values ('prj_D','D123',null,70,70);
```

this solution should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs !! I agree, putting multiple values in a cell is not a good approach. However, this approach has been implemented for a long time in this case and I am not allowed to change it. So, I went ahead with regexp_substr to handle the multiple values :

```
(select regexp_substr(t2.prj_alt_code,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
 connect by regexp_substr(t2.prj_alt_code, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

and a combination of union all prj_alt_code=null and prj_alt_code is not null to achieve the intended result.